# slam and virtual environment?

Tags: ros, slam, navigation, environment, teleoperation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I wanna know if this feasible. In the client side, I have a virtual environment where the slave is considered as a point that populates the virtual environment. In this environment, there are some fixed obstacles, so the slave will send the current position of the point as well as the positions of the obstacles. Based on the aforementioned data, I will visualize a map in the master side. Where should I start if this possible?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/68398/slam-and-virtual-environment?/) by [CroCo](https://answers.ros.org/users/4955/croco/) on ROS Answers with karma: 155 on 2013-07-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The short answer is "yes, this is possible."

It's hard to give a better answer without knowing more details of your system. What do you already have working? Are you starting from scratch? Have you worked through the basic ROS tutorials?

---

Originally posted by [lindzey](https://answers.ros.org/users/2444/lindzey/) with karma: 1780 on 2013-07-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [CroCo](https://answers.ros.org/users/4955/croco/) on 2013-07-25**:
@lindzey,
Thanks for the quick reply. I'm really struggling with ROS and to set up Phantom Omni in Ubuntu. It is really pain in the neck. At least now I want to acquaint my self with SLAM in general. I came across MRPT library. My question is how can I fake the positions of virtual obstacles?

**Comment by [CroCo](https://answers.ros.org/users/4955/croco/) on 2013-07-25**:
I will be more than happy if I implement simple SLAM whether by using ROS or MRPT. I'm reading probabilistic robotics book, however there is nothing about the practical stuff.